# Discord Poll Bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi i am trying to make a poll bot but ive encountered a problem here is the code ignore the other commands other than + poll

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random

pollid = 0
emoji1 = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
emoji2 = '\N{THUMBS DOWN SIGN}'
client = discord.Client()

sad_words=["sad","depressed", "unhappy","angry","miserable","depressing"]

starter_encouragements = ["Cheer up", "hang in there.", "You are a great person / bot!"]

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")

  json_data = json.loads(response.text)

  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return[quote]


from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global pollid
  #if message.author == client.user:
   # return
  msg = message.content

  if message.content.startswith('+encourage'):
    quote=get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)

  if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(starter_encouragements))

  if message.content.startswith("+joke"):
    from dadjokes import Dadjoke
    dadjoke = Dadjoke()
    await message.channel.send(dadjoke.joke)
  if message.content.startswith("+poll"):
    pollid = pollid+1
    await message.channel.send(content = msg.split(' ', 1)[1] + ' (number of polls made ' + str(pollid) + ')')
     
  if message.author == client.user:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji1)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji2)

  reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji1) 
    #reaction2 = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji2)
    #if (reaction != None and reaction2 != None):
     # totalcount = reaction.count + reaction2.count
    #if totalcount>=2:
  if (reaction != None and reaction.count != 1):
    await message.channel.send('The outcome of the poll is yes'+ str(reaction.count))
     
#  await message.channel.send('The outcome of the poll is no')
    

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

i am very new to python and the discord api for it ive been trying to set up a poll system where it has a timer on each poll that lasts 24 hrs and after 24 hrs it compares the amount of reactions on the message to see which side wins. Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `on_message` events for that but instead use a command.
You can do something like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, text: str):
    poll = await ctx.send(f"{text}")
    await poll.add_reaction("✅")
    await poll.add_reaction("❌")
```

Here we have `text` as a `str` so you can add as many text as you want.

If you want to compare it after 24 hours you would also have to build in a cooldown saver if the bot restarts, otherwise we could go with `await asyncio.sleep(TimeAmount)`

If you want to check the result with a command we could go for this:

```py
from discord.utils import get
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def results(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, msgID: int):
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msgID)
    reaction = get(msg.reactions, emoji='✅')
    count1 = reaction.count # Count the one reaction
    reaction2 = get(msg.reactions, emoji="❌")
    count2 = reaction2.count # Count the second reaction
    await ctx.send(f"✅**: {count1 - 1}** and ❌**: {count2 - 1}**") # -1 is used to exclude the bot
```

The usage of the command would be: `results #channel MSGID`.

Be aware that `fetch` is an API call and could cause a ratelimit.