# Count amount of thumbs up and thumbs down reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for polling on various servers, and my original method of counting votes has a major flaw. With it, people can react, take away the reaction, and re-add it multiple times and the vote will be counted every time. In short, it basically allows people to cast multiple ballots. Here's the code:

```
def check(reaction, user):
  return user != '808555253317894163' and str(reaction.emoji) in ['', '']

yay = 0
nay = 0
loop = 0

while loop == 0:
  try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=timeLimit, check=check)
    if reaction.emoji == '' and user != '808555253317894163':
      yay += 1
    if reaction.emoji == '' and user != '808555253317894163':
      nay += 1
  
except:
  await ctx.send(f'Yay: {yay}\nNay: {nay}')

  if yay > nay:
    await ctx.send('The vote comes out to yay!')
  elif yay < nay:
    await ctx.send('The vote comes out to nay!')
  elif yay == nay:
    await ctx.send('The vote is a tie!')
  
  loop = 1
```

I want to change it so that after the time limit, it counts the number of thumbs up and down reactions only, then subtracts 1 from each (to account for the bot's reaction). The only other post that was close to what I want asked to check for only a thumbs up reaction. Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: What is it doing right now? How is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Whenever someone adds a reaction, it checks the type of reaction they add, then increment "yay" or "nay", depending on if they chose thumbs up or thumbs down.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Counting things is a basic language skill, not a Stack Overflow problem.

Comment: I am wanting to find the amount of reactions of a certain emoji, and there are no answers that are helpful to me when I try to research. I'm no longer trying to count the reactions live. I'm trying to count the amount of thumbs up and thumbs down reactions separately from each other, as knowing the total amount of votes is useless if you don't know what people voted for.

Comment: Have you tried fetching the reactions? I made an answer to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288667/discord-poll-bot/66308471#66308471) a while ago, maybe that helps.

Comment: Whenever I tried that, I got an error when I used "get": "AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'reactions.'

Comment: Oh wait, didn't realize fetch_message is a coroutine, so I didn't await it.

Answer (score 0):

Using what Dominik said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288667/discord-poll-bot/66308471#66308471), I found the answer to my question:

```py
  while loop == 0:
    try:
      reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=timeLimit, check=check)
      
    except:
      # Find the poll message from its id
      msg = await vote_channel.fetch_message(pollID)
      
      # Count the amount of thumbs up reactions
      thumbUps = get(msg.reactions, emoji='')
      yay = thumbUps.count - 1

      # Count the amount of thumbs down reactions
      thumbDowns = get(msg.reactions, emoji='')
      nay = thumbDowns.count - 1

      loop = 1
```